# logical error with isalpha() and mutiple while loop

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, isalpha

i am trying to check if the  user is putting a alpha character for the input and if they don't it prints a string.  this whole program is for the user to pick if they want letter, numbers or special characters in there password.

this is my code that works but once i get to the special_characters while loop there is a logical error. when i type y i get the print("Invalied input, Try again! not y or n") in the else statement but if i enter n or anything else i get what the code does! i am very confused:

```
 import string

 alphabets = list(string.ascii_letters)
 digits = list(string.digits)
 special_characters = list("!@#$%^&*()")
 PasswordCharacters = []

a = True
while a:
  x = True
  y = True
  z = True
  while x:
     alphabets_2 = input("Would you like to include letters in your password?: ")

    if alphabets_2.isalpha():
        if alphabets_2 == "y":
            PasswordCharacters.append(alphabets)
            x = False
        elif alphabets_2 == 'n':
            x = False
        else:
            print("Invail Input, Try Again! not y or n")
    if not alphabets_2.isalpha():
        print("Invaild input! Try again, not a letter")
        continue

  while y:
    digits_2 = input("Would you like to include digits in your password?: ")

    if digits_2.isalpha():
        if digits_2 == 'y':
            PasswordCharacters.append(digits)
            y = False
        elif digits_2 == 'n':
            y = False
        else:
            print("Invaild Input, Try Again! not y or n")
    if not digits_2.isalpha():
        print("Invaild input! Try Again! not a letter")
        continue

  while z:
    special_characters_2 = input("would you like to include special characters in your password?: ")

    if special_characters_2.isalpha():
        if special_characters == 'y':
            PasswordCharacters.append(special_characters)
            z = False
        elif special_characters_2 == 'n':
            z = False
        else:
            print("Invaild input, Try again! not y or n")
    if not special_characters_2.isalpha():
        print("Invaild input, Try again! not a letter")
        continue
a = False
```

i get a logical error that when i enter y i get the print statement for the else block

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
    if special_characters_2.isalpha():
        if special_characters == 'y':  # should be special_characters_2
```

It's easy to have typos like this when you have a lot of copied and pasted code.  Consider putting this question-and-answer loop in a function:

```
def ask_y_or_n(question):
    while True:
        answer = input(question)
        if answer == "y":
            return True
        if answer == "n":
            return False
        if answer.isalpha():
            print("Invaild Input, Try Again! not y or n")
        else:
            print("Invaild input! Try Again! not a letter")
```

Then you can replace the entirety of the x/y/z section of the code with:

```
for desc, characters in [
    ("letters", alphabets),
    ("digits", digits),
    ("special characters", special_characters),
]:
    if ask_y_or_n(f"Would you like to include {desc} in your password?: "):
        PasswordCharacters.append(characters)
```

Comment: WOW!! a typo is the one thing that will annoy a programmer 100% of the time!! thanks my guy!

Answer (score 0):

A typo:

```py
if special_characters == 'y':
```

Should be `special_characters2`.

And you dont actually need to convert string.ascii_letters and etc. to a list because it is basically.. a list already

Comment: i tried it and it just puts it into a string

Comment: `PasswordCharacters` could itself just be a string (use `+=` instead of `append`).